# Why is id of object returned by session._get_current_object() is changed on every request, while id of session remains unchanged?

Tags: python, python-3.x, session, flask, request

I am using:

- Python 3.6.1
- Flask 0.12.2

---

[Section on `session`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.session) of Flask documentation says that:

> This is a proxy.

and [section on proxies](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/reqcontext/#notes-on-proxies) elaborates that:

> Some of the objects provided by Flask are proxies to other objects.
>   The reason behind this is that these proxies are shared between
>   threads and they have to dispatch to the actual object bound to a
>   thread behind the scenes as necessary. 
>  ... 
>  
>   If you need to get access
>   to the underlying object that is proxied, you can use the
>   [`_get_current_object()`](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/0.15.x/local/#werkzeug.local.LocalProxy._get_current_object) method

This all is pretty much straightforward.

But when I try the following:

```
from flask import (
Flask,
session,
)

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'some random secret key'

@app.route('/')
def index():
    print("session ID is: {}".format(id(session)))
    print("session._get_current_object() ID is: {}".format(id(session._get_current_object())))
    print('________________________________')

    return 'Check the console! ;-)'
```

each time I make a request to `/` — the value of `id(session._get_current_object())` is different, while `id(session)` remains the same.

Following [Flask documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/), quoted above, it should be the other way around. So why is this happening?

---

**UPDATE** 

*inspired by [brunns](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1073696/brunns)'s suggestion in the comments to [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55758011/8554766), that there is one underlying object per thread*

Here is some code, to test assumption that there is one underlying `session` object (`session._get_current_object()`) per thread:

```
import threading

from flask import (
Flask,
session,
)

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'some random secret key'

@app.route('/')
def index():
    print("session ID is: {}".format(id(session)))
    print("session._get_current_object() ID is: {}".format(id(session._get_current_object())))
    print("threading.current_thread().ident is: {}".format(threading.current_thread().ident))
    print('________________________________')
    return 'Check the console! ;-)'
```

Despite the expectations, `threading.current_thread().ident)` is never changed, while is `id(session._get_current_object()` is changing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`session` is an object you have imported from the `flask` module. You only import it once, and it doesn't change, so nor will its `id()`. It's shared between threads, and it's a proxy to the underlying objects.

Each request may be run on a different thread, and each will have a different underlying object, so they may have different `id()`s.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think, I now understand why `id(session)` never changes. Though I am still confused about `session._get_current_object()`. Could you please elaborate on the following: what `session` is proxying to, if the underlying object is changed after each request ? My (_incorrect_) understanding is (_?was_) is that there is only one underlying object for all threads (which remains unchanged, for the session's lifetime), and `session` is a proxy to that object. What is, then, returned by `session._get_current_object()`? Is it also a proxy object (if so, what is it proxying to)?

Comment: My understanding was that there was one underlying object ber thread (not per request) so you'll see many different `id`s, but there will be repeats.

Beyond that, sorry, but you're getting beyond my knowledge!

Comment: Thanks for sharing your knowledge, it helped me to advance my own understanding of the matter.

Comment: Though, I have tested if `session._get_current_object()` is changing together with thread id — and it is not (see example I have added to the question).

Comment: You, might be interested by [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55809062/8554766) to my another question, which explains that object proxied by `session` is, in fact, belongs to [`RequestContext`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.ctx.RequestContext).

Comment: The proxied session objects are created for each and every request, so their ids are expected to be different.